# Can't we approach the equation $e^{\sin x} - e^{-\sin x} - 4 = 0$

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms, exponentiation

Forgetting for a moment that the equation $e^{\sin x} - e^{-\sin x} - 4 = 0$ has no real solution, if we approach  the final equation (which we get after solving the above equation)

$e^{\sin x} = 2 \pm \sqrt 5$

and do log on both sides then we get

$\log e^{\sin x} = \log (2 \pm \sqrt 5)$

$\implies \sin x = \log(2 + \sqrt 5)$ (as $\log (2 - \sqrt 5$ is a complex number)

$\implies \sin x = 0.626962921 \in [-1,1]$

Thus $x$ ought to have a real root on the above value, but it doesn't.

***What is wrong with this approach besides not getting required result ?***

Comment: Where does $2 \pm \sqrt 5$ comes from?  Why not take $e^{\sin x}=1,000,000?$  What does it mean to approach an equation?

Comment: Well, e^sinx = 2±√5 is the equation we get, if we solve the equation e^sinx + e^-sinx - 4..

Comment: First off, that should be $2 \pm \sqrt3.$ Second off, $2 + \sqrt3 > 3 > e$ so $\log (2+\sqrt3) > 1,$ so this also has no real solutions. The value you give for $\log(2 + \sqrt5)$ is for a log of base $10,$ not the natural log. (which here is what i mean by simply $\log,$ to be clear)

Comment: It is 2±√5. Let's take ur assumption to be true for a moment, my doubt is log(2+√3) value lies b/w 0 &1 why it cant satisfy Range of Sinx & be a solution?

Comment: First, it is $2\pm \sqrt 3$: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+x%5E2-4x%2B1%3D0  Secondly,  $\log(2+\sqrt 3)$ is about 1.3:  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%282%2Bsqrt+3%29

Comment: Do read kindly my question & comment again! Thanks.

Comment: When I solve the quadratic in $e^{\sin x}$ I get $e^{\sin x} = 2 \pm \sqrt 3$. Redo your quadratic, you get $z^2 - 4 z + 1 = 0$ where $z = e^{\sin x}$.

Comment: The questions in the body and title are different. You also applied the base-10 logarithm to both sides when you should use ln instead: $\log_{10} e^{\sin x} \ne \sin x$.

Comment: Well, in question what i 'declared' is different approach is shown in body as a doubt. Indeed, i knew my mistake now to use cautiously logbase10. Thanks! @Toby Mak

Answer (score 2):

For a start, $e^{\sin x} + e^{-\sin x} - 4 = 0$ yields the quadratic equation:

$$z^2 - 4 z + 1 = 0$$
where $z = e^{\sin x}$.

This yields:
$$z = \dfrac {-(-4) \pm \sqrt {(-4)^2 - 4 \times 1 \times 1} } {2 \times 1} = 2 \pm \sqrt 3$$

This gives $2 + \sqrt 3 \approx 3.73$ and $2 - \sqrt 3 \approx 0.26$

Taking **natural** logarithms of this gives $$\sin x = \ln (2 + \sqrt 3) \approx 1.31, \sin x = \ln (2 - \sqrt 3) \approx -1.31$$

neither of which yields a real solution for $\sin x$.

Your biggest mistake is taking the **logarithm base 10** when you should be taking the **logarithm base $e$**.

EDIT: I note that the equation in the title *does* show $e^{\sin x} - e^{-\sin x} - 4 = 0$ which is **different from what is in the body of the question**.

It is this sort of carelessness which you need to guard against.

In this case, yes, you are correct, $z = 2 \pm \sqrt 5$.

But then:
$$\sin x = \ln (2 + \sqrt 5) \approx 1.44$$

which again has no real solution in $x$.

Comment: Thankyou man, For clarifying my views! Well from now on i would be cautious doing logbase10, surely use ln instead. Btw i don't care whether it is 2±√3 or 2±√5, my doubt was* not there at all!

Comment: Yes indeed. The inverse of $e^x$ is $\ln x$. That is: $y = e^x \iff x = \ln y$. But note that $y = 10^x \iff x = \log_{10} y$. And, as I say, *please* guard against the sort of carelessness that writes an equation incorrectly in the first place, *especially* when you have responders who reply with the fact that it *is* an error. It wastes our time.

Comment: Noted in my memory palace! Thanks. Will surely take care from next time .